# Frame Y not changing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, frame

This is a custom navigation bar, made from a UIView. It doesn't take control of it's setter method for setFrame. I feel like maybe i'm missing something simple.

```
if (self.statusBarHiddenInitially == NO) {
        self.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.navigationBar.frame.origin.x,
                                              20,
                                              self.navigationBar.frame.size.width,
                                              self.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
        NSLog(@"test frame: %f", self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y);
    }
```

Test frame returns `0.000000`.

Comment: Do you create it in code, or in IB? Could be auto-sizing.

Comment: In code. It has autoresizing set to width.

Comment: I'd try turning off autosizing and retest just to eliminate that as the culprit.

Comment: Just done that. Turns out that is the problem. Not sure why it would be doing that though?